# React Formik onSubmit RestAPI called twice, once click a submit button

Tags: reactjs, formik

I'm using Formik and Yup in react, when I click submit button and the onSubmit event firing, And inside of the event the fetch function called twice,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import { TextField } from 'formik-material-ui';
import { Formik, Field, Form } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
class LoginForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {classes: this.props.classes, isLoading: false }
    }
render() {
   return (
        <Formik
            initialValues={initialFormValues}
            validationSchema={validationFrom}
            onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
                this.setState({ isLoading: true });
                console.log(values);
                actions.setSubmitting(false);
                console.log('SUCCESS!! :-)\n\n' + JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));

                fetch('http://xx.xx.xx.xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9000/api/v1/userAuth', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(values)
                })
                    .then(Response => {
                        console.log(Response);
                        this.setState({ isLoading: false });
                    })
               }
            }
            render={({ submitForm, isSubmitting, isValid }) => (
                <Form>
                    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs" >
                        <div className={this.state.classes.paper}>
                            <Field
                                variant="outlined" margin="normal" fullWidth label="User ID" name="userid" id="userid" type="text"
                                autoComplete="userid" component={TextField} />
                            <Field
                                variant="outlined" margin="normal" fullWidth id="password" name="password" label="Password" type="password"
                                autoComplete="current-password" component={TextField} />

                            <Button
                                type="submit" fullWidth variant="contained" color="primary"
                                    className={this.state.classes.submit} disabled={isSubmitting || !isValid}
                                > Sign In
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                    </Container>
                </Form>
            )}
        />
    )
 }
}
export default LoginForm;
```

I'm new to React, I have google it but no luck, Here is my tried code, I called the API for user Authentication to verify userId and password, Please suggest me to do correct way to call API.

[image]

Comment: Please post some relevant code

Comment: We need to see your whole React Component to be able to understand what's not working.

Comment: hi @technogeek1995, updated my working code, please have a look above.

Answer (score 5):

I see that the first call is 0 bytes.

Although I cannot see the detail of your *XHR* call, IMHO the first call is not a *POST* verb but an *OPTION*, as you are probably doing a network **request to a backend domain that is different from the domain where React app is served from**.

In *OPTION* call the server authorizes or deny the access to an endpoint on the basis of *CORS*. So, nothing strange, in my opinion.